# Error in php : free() invalid next size

Tags: php, free, libc

So basicly , I really dont know whats happening , everything working but I got this error which I really dont know. Any ideas ?

Installed apache serving php.
Error is not making things not work but I want to solve if there is a solutions. Btw I'm sorry that if that info is not enough.

Fresque is a command line tool for php-resque.

```
var/www/html/social-project/vendor/fresque/fresque# *** Error in `php': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000564fe3ad5be0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f882c55e7e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f882c56737a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f882c56b53c]
php(cleanup_ps_args+0x91)[0x564fe36d5971]
php(main+0x3c4)[0x564fe34b8704]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f882c507830]
php(_start+0x29)[0x564fe34b88f9]
======= Memory map: ========
564fe33d4000-564fe3784000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 59250                      /usr/bin/php7.0
564fe3984000-564fe39fd000 r--p 003b0000 fd:01 59250                      /usr/bin/php7.0
564fe39fd000-564fe3a0d000 rw-p 00429000 fd:01 59250                      /usr/bin/php7.0
564fe3a0d000-564fe3a29000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
564fe3ac3000-564fe3c90000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f8824000000-7f8824021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8824021000-7f8828000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f8829cc5000-7f8829cdb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1964                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8829cdb000-7f8829eda000 ---p 00016000 fd:01 1964                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8829eda000-7f8829edb000 rw-p 00015000 fd:01 1964                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f8829edb000-7f882a04d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 25730                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f882a04d000-7f882a24d000 ---p 00172000 fd:01 25730                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f882a24d000-7f882a257000 r--p 00172000 fd:01 25730                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f882a257000-7f882a259000 rw-p 0017c000 fd:01 25730                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f882a259000-7f882a25d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882a25d000-7f882bb13000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 25930                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f882bb13000-7f882bd12000 ---p 018b6000 fd:01 25930                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f882bd12000-7f882bd13000 r--p 018b5000 fd:01 25930                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f882bd13000-7f882bd14000 rw-p 018b6000 fd:01 25930                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
7f882bd14000-7f882bd35000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2003                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f882bd35000-7f882bf34000 ---p 00021000 fd:01 2003                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f882bf34000-7f882bf35000 r--p 00020000 fd:01 2003                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f882bf35000-7f882bf36000 rw-p 00021000 fd:01 2003                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
7f882bf36000-7f882c0b5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 25932                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f882c0b5000-7f882c2b5000 ---p 0017f000 fd:01 25932                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f882c2b5000-7f882c2c5000 r--p 0017f000 fd:01 25932                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f882c2c5000-7f882c2c6000 rw-p 0018f000 fd:01 25932                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.55.1
7f882c2c6000-7f882c2ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882c2ca000-7f882c2e2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1971                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f882c2e2000-7f882c4e1000 ---p 00018000 fd:01 1971                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f882c4e1000-7f882c4e2000 r--p 00017000 fd:01 1971                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f882c4e2000-7f882c4e3000 rw-p 00018000 fd:01 1971                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f882c4e3000-7f882c4e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882c4e7000-7f882c6a7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1994                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f882c6a7000-7f882c8a7000 ---p 001c0000 fd:01 1994                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f882c8a7000-7f882c8ab000 r--p 001c0000 fd:01 1994                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f882c8ab000-7f882c8ad000 rw-p 001c4000 fd:01 1994                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7f882c8ad000-7f882c8b1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882c8b1000-7f882cacb000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2113                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f882cacb000-7f882ccca000 ---p 0021a000 fd:01 2113                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f882ccca000-7f882cce6000 r--p 00219000 fd:01 2113                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f882cce6000-7f882ccf2000 rw-p 00235000 fd:01 2113                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f882ccf2000-7f882ccf5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882ccf5000-7f882cd53000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2114                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f882cd53000-7f882cf53000 ---p 0005e000 fd:01 2114                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f882cf53000-7f882cf57000 r--p 0005e000 fd:01 2114                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f882cf57000-7f882cf5e000 rw-p 00062000 fd:01 2114                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
7f882cf5e000-7f882d10f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 25943                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f882d10f000-7f882d30e000 ---p 001b1000 fd:01 25943                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f882d30e000-7f882d316000 r--p 001b0000 fd:01 25943                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f882d316000-7f882d318000 rw-p 001b8000 fd:01 25943                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.3
7f882d318000-7f882d319000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882d319000-7f882d31c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1977                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f882d31c000-7f882d51b000 ---p 00003000 fd:01 1977                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f882d51b000-7f882d51c000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 1977                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f882d51c000-7f882d51d000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 1977                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f882d51d000-7f882d625000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1989                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f882d625000-7f882d824000 ---p 00108000 fd:01 1989                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f882d824000-7f882d825000 r--p 00107000 fd:01 1989                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f882d825000-7f882d826000 rw-p 00108000 fd:01 1989                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f882d826000-7f882d894000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f882d894000-7f882da94000 ---p 0006e000 fd:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f882da94000-7f882da95000 r--p 0006e000 fd:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f882da95000-7f882da96000 rw-p 0006f000 fd:01 2062                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.2
7f882da96000-7f882daaf000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 2119                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f882daaf000-7f882dcae000 ---p 00019000 fd:01 2119                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f882dcae000-7f882dcaf000 r--p 00018000 fd:01 2119                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f882dcaf000-7f882dcb0000 rw-p 00019000 fd:01 2119                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
7f882dcb0000-7f882dcc7000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1984                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f882dcc7000-7f882dec7000 ---p 00017000 fd:01 1984                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f882dec7000-7f882dec8000 r--p 00017000 fd:01 1984                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f882dec8000-7f882dec9000 rw-p 00018000 fd:01 1984                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f882dec9000-7f882decb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882decb000-7f882def1000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1966                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f882df45000-7f882e0dd000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 28901                      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f882e0dd000-7f882e0e7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882e0ed000-7f882e0ee000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882e0ee000-7f882e0f0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f882e0f0000-7f882e0f1000 r--p 00025000 fd:01 1966                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f882e0f1000-7f882e0f2000 rw-p 00026000 fd:01 1966                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f882e0f2000-7f882e0f3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fff9c83b000-7fff9c85c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff9c917000-7fff9c919000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff9c919000-7fff9c91b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

So I tested with valgrind and here is the result.

```
==5951== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5951== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5951== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5951== Command: ./fresque
==5951== Parent PID: 15505
==5951== 
--5951-- 
--5951-- Valgrind options:
--5951--    --tool=memcheck
--5951--    --num-callers=30
--5951--    --log-file=log.log
--5951--    -v
--5951-- Contents of /proc/version:
--5951--   Linux version 4.4.0-97-generic (buildd@lcy01-33) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017
--5951-- 
--5951-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-lzcnt-rdtscp-sse3-avx-avx2-bmi
--5951-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--5951-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--5951-- Reading syms from /bin/bash
--5951--   Considering /bin/bash ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed c27dcca5 wanted 5aa3c568)
--5951--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5951-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
--5951--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 9bc477cd wanted 3da2f12a)
--5951--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC is valid
--5951-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--5951--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed eea41ea9 wanted 2009db78)
--5951--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5951--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--5951-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--5951-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==5951== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5951-by-root-on-???
==5951== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5951-by-root-on-???
==5951== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5951-by-root-on-???
==5951== 
==5951== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==5951== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==5951== or are doing some strange experiment):
==5951==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5951 ...command...
==5951== 
==5951== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==5951==   /path/to/gdb ./fresque
==5951== and then give GDB the following command
==5951==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5951
==5951== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==5951== 
--5951-- REDIR: 0x401cf90 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x3809e181 (???)
--5951-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--5951--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 2567ccf6 wanted 49420590)
--5951--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5951-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--5951--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 0e27c9a8 wanted ac585421)
--5951--    object doesn't have a symbol table
==5951== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--5951--     old: 0x0401cf90 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x3809e181 ???
--5951--     new: 0x0401cf90 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c31020 strlen
--5951-- REDIR: 0x401b8e0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x4c30bc0 (index)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x401bb00 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c320d0 (strcmp)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x401dcf0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c35270 (mempcpy)
--5951-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
--5951--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--5951-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
--5951--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed cf3e24b0 wanted fd1ac2a8)
--5951--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC is valid
--5951-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
--5951--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC mismatch (computed b2979fac wanted 1affc958)
--5951--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so ..
--5951--   .. CRC is valid
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f6a00 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f2280 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f8cf0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f46f0 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f4a80 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f614b (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f4400 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4c308a0 (rindex)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f0d10 (libc.so.6:__GI_strcmp) redirected to 0x4c31fe0 (__GI_strcmp)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f2720 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x4c30f60 (strlen)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f2b70 (libc.so.6:__GI_strncmp) redirected to 0x4c31710 (__GI_strncmp)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f0ab0 (libc.so.6:__GI_strchr) redirected to 0x4c30a00 (__GI_strchr)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f5860 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x4c32170 (memchr)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52fd760 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x4c34da0 (strchrnul)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f63b0 (libc.so.6:__GI_mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c34fa0 (__GI_mempcpy)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52fb470 (libc.so.6:__GI_memcpy) redirected to 0x4c32b00 (__GI_memcpy)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f61b0 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x53d9930 (libc.so.6:__memset_avx2) redirected to 0x4c344c0 (memset)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f2160 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x530c9d0 (libc.so.6:__strcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c31040 (strcpy)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f2b20 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x53aca50 (libc.so.6:__strncmp_sse42) redirected to 0x4c317f0 (__strncmp_sse42)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f0cd0 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x5306570 (libc.so.6:__strcmp_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c31f90 (strcmp)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f28c0 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x4c30ee0 (strnlen)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x537d440 (libc.so.6:__strcpy_chk) redirected to 0x4c34e10 (__strcpy_chk)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f0a80 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52fb3f0 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x53b4e60 (libc.so.6:__memcpy_avx_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c324a0 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14)
==5954== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5954-by-root-on-???
==5954== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5954-by-root-on-???
==5954== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5954-by-root-on-???
==5954== 
==5954== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==5954== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==5954== or are doing some strange experiment):
==5954==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5954 ...command...
==5954== 
==5954== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==5954==   /path/to/gdb ./fresque
==5954== and then give GDB the following command
==5954==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5954
==5954== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==5954== 
==5955== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5955-by-root-on-???
==5955== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5955-by-root-on-???
==5955== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5955-by-root-on-???
==5955== 
==5955== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==5955== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==5955== or are doing some strange experiment):
==5955==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5955 ...command...
==5955== 
==5955== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==5955==   /path/to/gdb ./fresque
==5955== and then give GDB the following command
==5955==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5955
==5955== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==5955== 
==5955== 
==5955== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5955==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5955==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5955== 
==5955== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5955== 
==5955== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5955== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5954== 
==5954== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5954==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5954==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==5954== 
==5954== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5954== 
==5954== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5954== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5957== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-5957-by-root-on-???
==5957== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-5957-by-root-on-???
==5957== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5957-by-root-on-???
==5957== 
==5957== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==5957== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==5957== or are doing some strange experiment):
==5957==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5957 ...command...
==5957== 
==5957== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==5957==   /path/to/gdb ./fresque
==5957== and then give GDB the following command
==5957==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5957
==5957== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==5957== 
--5951-- REDIR: 0x52f43c0 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--5951-- REDIR: 0x530d000 (libc.so.6:__strncpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c31570 (__strncpy_sse2_unaligned)
```

However , this make non-sense because the command line tool makes a runtime environment for example ,

```
./fresque start -> calls workers.(runtime)
```

Comment: Post the code that causes this error.

Comment: How can I identify ? I'm using a library . is there any function that may cause this ? @AlexHowansky

Comment: It's probably a bug in the tool. You could run it under valgrind in an attempt to get more information about the location of the bug.

Comment: I tested but I dont know is it possible. given in the edit @FlorianWeimer